# Create table with frequency buckets in Base SAS

Tags: sas

Below is a sample of my dataset:

> City Days
>
> Atlanta 10
>
> Tampa  95
>
> Atlanta  100
>
> Charlotte  20
>
> Charlotte   31
>
> Tampa 185

I would like to break down "Days" into buckets of 0-30, 30-90, 90-180, 180+, such that the "buckets" are along the x-axis of the table, and the cities are along the y-axis.

I tried using PROC FREQ, but I don't have SAS/STAT. Is there any way to do this in base SAS?

Comment: Pretty sure that PROC FREQ is a BASE proc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want. This is most certainly a "brute force" approach, but I think its outlines the concept correctly.

```
data have;
length city $9;
input city dayscount;
cards;
Atlanta 10 
Tampa 95
Atlanta 100
Charlotte 20
Charlotte 31
Tampa 185
;
run;

data want;
set have;
if dayscount >= 0 and dayscount <=30 then '0-30'n = dayscount;
if dayscount >= 30 and dayscount <=90 then '30-90'n = dayscount;
if dayscount >= 90 and dayscount <=180 then '90-180'n = dayscount;
if dayscount > 180 then '180+'n = dayscount;
drop dayscount;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways for solving this problem is by using **Proc Format** for assigning the value bucket and then using **Proc Transpose** for the desired result:

```
data city_day_split;
length city $12.;
input city dayscount;
cards;
atlanta 10 
tampa 95
atlanta 100
charlotte 20
charlotte 31
tampa 185
;
run;

/****Assigning the buckets****/
proc format;
value buckets
0 - <30 = '0-30'
30 - <90 = '30-90'
90 - <180 = '90-180'
180 - high = 'gte180'
;
run;

data city_day_split;
set city_day_split;
day_bucket = put(dayscount,buckets.);
run;

proc sort data=city_day_split out=city_day_split;
by city;
run;

/****Making the Buckets as columns, City as rows and daycount as Value****/
proc transpose data=city_day_split out=city_day_split_1(drop=_name_);
by city;
id day_bucket;
var dayscount;
run;
```

**My Output:**

```
> **city    |0-30  |90-180  |30-90  |GTE180**
> Atlanta   |10    |100     |.      |.
> Charlotte |20    |.       |31     |.
> Tampa     |.     |95      |.      |185
```